# while positing to facebook how to give a hyperlink with the message content

Tags: php

I'm trying to post to facebook wall using graph api.
  I could do it.. but i need to give a hyperlink to the message content and it is not  happenning with the  tag.. 
I need somthing like  "message" => "My message and my link" 
can anyone please help me out...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$link = "http://www.somedomain.com/someting";
$attachment = array(
"message" => $message, 
"link" => $link);

// OR If you just want to show link then
$newLink = "<a href='http://www.somesite.com/somepageToShowMEssage'>Click Here</a>";
//try just adding the link as attachment
$attachment = array(
"link" => $newLink 
);

$sendMessage = $objFacebook->api("/$sendToId/feed/", "post", $attachment);
```

Comment: but i need to add an extra hyperlink with the "message"  ie: "message" => $message+my hyperlink.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, then you could just do: "message" => $message . $link;  ... isnt it..?

Comment: yes this is right.. but here the whole link wil get posted. is it not possible to add a link just like an html hyper lik so that instead of the http link just a string like 'click' will appear there.

Comment: and where will be the message displayed on clicking on "Click Here" link ..?

Comment: that will be a link to another site. like www.somesite.com

Comment: see edited code after comment //OR.. Do you mean something like that..?

Comment: See the optput of that : Soumya Raj
Learnt an article on ocus<a href='http://www.apple.com/itunes/'>Click Here</a> , the whole link is getting displayed instead of "click here"